# How to solve a problem with inequality

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

```
sr[r_] = A + B r^-2;(*stress function*)
c1 = 10;(*edge condition at a*)
a = 1;(*location of edge*)
sa = 10;(*stress on the edge r=a*)
Solve[{
`sr[a] == sa,
sr[0]!=\[Infinity]}, {A,B}] (*B should be zero and A should be sa*)
```

This is the code. It is  a simple equation with 2 unknown constants A,B and 2 equations (edge conditions). The problem is that I know the solution, but i don't know how to program Solve function/equation, because of the inequality with infinity, solve returns an error (shown on the picture below).

[image]

Comment: You didn't show the inequality!

Comment: It is inside solve - one of the conditions is that stress  sr[0] can't be infinity. 
So A + B/0^2 != infinity. The only way this is possible if B is zero, but mathetmatica only encounters problem of dividing with zero.